# Streamlines in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, fluid-dynamics, streamline

Can someone suggest a better way to solve for streamlines in Mathematica?
P.S. StreamPlot is not providing accurate results.

Here, velocity is `u[x,y] i + v0[x,y] j`. `p0x[x]` is the pressure gradient. The last line in the code is taking too long to execute a simpler solution will be appreciated.

code is as follows :

```
B1[x_] = 1 + a*Cos[2*Pi*x];

p0x[x_] = -1/B1[x];

u0[x_, y_] = -p0x[x];

v0[x_, y_] = D[p0x[x], x]*y;

u1[x_, y_] = \[Lambda]^2*D[p0x[x], {x, 2}]/2*y^2 - \[Lambda]^2* D[p0x[x], {x, 2}]/6*(B1[x])^2;

u[x_, y_] = -p0x[x] + \[Delta]^2*\[Lambda]^2*D[p0x[x], {x, 2}]/2*(y^2 - (B1[x])^2/3);

eq = (D[y[x], x] == v0[x, y[x]]/u[x, y[x]]) /. {a -> 0.3, \[Lambda] -> 1, \[Delta] -> 1} ;

sl = DSolve[eq, y[x], x]
```

Comment: Might get a better response in the mathematica site https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh. Thanks.
That is definitely a better idea.